# Why does my framebuffer not work when rendering to texture?

Tags: opengl, c++, textures

I am having trouble rendering to a texture and then mapping that texture to a quad. I am using OpenGL 2.0. I am using code from the wiki. The class scene_t has a texture called _out_tex, which is the texture that game_window_t will map to a quad filling the entire screen:

Code in main.c:

```
game_window_t gwin;
gwin.w = 800;
gwin.h = 600;
gwin.title = (char *) "2D Lighting";
gfx::create_window(&gwin);

math::poly2d poly;
poly.add_vertex(math::vec2f(400.0f, 0.0f));
poly.add_vertex(math::vec2f(0.0f,   600.0f));
poly.add_vertex(math::vec2f(800.0f, 600.0f));

gfx::object_t o;
o.set_color(math::vec4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
o.shape = &poly;

if(scene.set_parent_window(&gwin) < 0)
{
    printf("Error setting parent window\n");
    goto panic;
}

scene.add_object(&o);

scene.render();
gwin.put_scene(&scene);
gfx::flip(&gwin);
```

Code in scene.cpp:

```
char scene_t::set_parent_window(game_window_t *win)
{
    _parent_win = win;
    _w = win->w;
    _h = win->h;

     //RGBA8 2D texture, 24 bit depth texture, 256x256
   glGenTextures(1, &_out_tex);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _out_tex);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   //NULL means reserve texture memory, but texels are undefined
   //**** Tell OpenGL to reserve level 0
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, _w, _h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
   //You must reserve memory for other mipmaps levels as well either by making a series of calls to
   //glTexImage2D or use glGenerateMipmapEXT(GL_TEXTURE_2D).
   //Here, we'll use :
   glGenerateMipmapEXT(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   //-------------------------
   glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &_fbuf);
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, _fbuf);
   //Attach 2D texture to this FBO
   glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _out_tex, 0);
   //-------------------------
   glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &_depth_rb);
   glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, _depth_rb);
   glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, _w, _h);
   //-------------------------
   //Attach depth buffer to FBO
   glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, _depth_rb);
   //-------------------------
   //Does the GPU support current FBO configuration?
   GLenum status;
   status = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);

   if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT)
   {
        printf("Error setting up framebuffer\n"); return -1;
   }

    return 0;
}

void scene_t::render()
{
    // render to texture
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, _fbuf);
    glViewport(0, 0, _w, _h);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for(int i = 0; i < _objects.size(); i++)
    {
        _objects[i]->render();
    }

    return;
}
```

Code in game_window.cpp:

```
char game_window_t::put_scene(scene_t *s)
{
    // if(s->_parent_win != this) { printf("SCENE DOES NOT BELONG TO WINDOW\n"); return -1; }

    // begin texture mapping
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT | GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, s->_out_tex);

    printf("tex: %u\n", s->_out_tex);

    // glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3d(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);    // top left
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 600.0f);     // bottom left
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(800.0f, 600.0f);    // bottom right
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(800.0f, 0.0f);   // top right
    glEnd();

    printf("put!\n");
}
```

object_t::render() just renders a triangle strip with the vertices of its shape polygon.

I don't understand why the texture (or whatever is rendered in game_window_t::put_scene()) is just black. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am aware that I am using a somewhat deprecated and outdated version of OGL, but I don't need the functionality of 3+ as far as I am concerned.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing any `data` to `glTexImage2D` -- the last parameter, per the docs, "Specifies a pointer to the image data in memory." (see: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

Since your `target` (first param) is GL_TEXTURE_2D, relevant info from link:

> If target is GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE or one of the
>   GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP targets, data is read from data as a sequence of
>   signed or unsigned bytes, shorts, or longs, or single-precision
>   floating-point values, depending on type. These values are grouped
>   into sets of one, two, three, or four values, depending on format, to
>   form elements. Each data byte is treated as eight 1-bit elements, with
>   bit ordering determined by GL_UNPACK_LSB_FIRST

Try giving that function a small set of data and see if it works. From https://open.gl/textures, the following should give you a black and white checker board pattern.

```
float pixels[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _w, _h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

NB: I did have to alter the above slightly to fit into what you have, but the general idea is the same.